# Convert a factor to column to numeric R

Tags: r, numeric, r-factor

I bring in a data set using the following command:

```
rbc <- read.csv("rbc hgb.csv", header = T)
data <- rbc[rbc$Result_Value_After != "NULL",]
```

For some reason the `rbc$Result_Value_After` gets treated like a factor, so I issue the following command:

```
data$Result_Value_After <- as.numeric(data$Result_Value_After)
```

The str(data) tells me the column is now of type `num` but all numbers that were factors are in decimal form like 7.2. When I do the conversion it gets changed to 72, which is way off. Any ideas on how to go about fixing this?

Comment: Also in read.csv you can add the arg as.is=T and it will prevent conversion to factor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible workaround for the issue of column classification upon calling `read.csv`.

Say I don't want to mess around with changing classes after reading data into R.  If I want one column to be `character` and the others as the default class, I can use `readLines` to quickly read the first line of the *.csv* (i.e. the column header line, if present) and set up a vector to be passed to the `colClasses` argument of `read.csv`.

Here's a simple function,

```
col.classes <- function(csv, col, class){
    g <- readLines(csv, n = 1)
    n <- unlist(strsplit(g, ","))
    col.classes <- ifelse(n %in% col, class, NA)
    return(col.classes)
}
```

To show how this works, suppose I have a file named *cats.csv* (and it just so happens that I do), and I know I want the *weight* column to be class `character` and the rest of the columns as the default class. Keep in mind that `colClasses` can be a character vector, and for elements that are `NA`, the corresponding column of data is skipped and classed as if read without `colClasses`.

View the names of the columns in the file

```
names(read.csv('cats.csv'))
## [1] "cats"   "colour" "length" "weight" "mu"
```

View the default classes from `read.csv`

```
> sapply(read.csv('cats.csv'), class)
##      cats    colour    length    weight       mu 
## "integer"  "factor" "integer" "integer" "integer"
```

**Sample Runs:**

(1) Class the *length* column as `numeric` upon calling `read.csv`, while leaving others as their respective defaults

```
> cc1 <- col.classes('cats.csv', 'length', 'numeric')
> rr1 <- read.csv('cats.csv', colClasses = cc1)
> sapply(rr1, class)
## cats    colour    length    weight       mu 
## "integer"  "factor" "numeric" "integer" "integer"
```

(2) Similarly, class the *weight* column as `character`

```
> cc2 <- col.classes('cats.csv', 'weight', 'character')
> rr2 <- read.csv('cats.csv', colClasses = cc2)
> sapply(rr2, class)
## cats      colour      length      weight         mu 
## "integer"    "factor"   "integer" "character"   "integer"
```

Not sure if that helps you at all.  I find it useful when I want a mixture of column classes that might otherwise be clunky and frustrating to change once the data has already been loaded into R.

Comment: Thanks for the post and great examples